# overlapping variables and performance

Tags: performance, variables, assembly, intervals, overlapping

Sorry in advance if I have some of this wrong. I may edit to correct later if it's not too disruptive.

When multiple variables are declared in adjacent memory, as I understand it, on a very low level, registers are created that encapsulate a number of bytes, commonly 1, 2, 4 or 8. This allows those bit ranges to be binary rotated, as well as thought of by the processor as numbers and so mutated with simple mathematics such as add, subtract, multiply and devide.

There may be abstraction reasons for not overlapping thease ranges, but as many langueges consider instructions to occur in a well defined sequential order that the coder will be aware of, are there any performance reasons to not overlap one or more in adjacent bytes of allocated memory?

For example in a block of allocated memory where every bit starts as 0. Bytes 0 to 3 could be being used as an int, as well as bytes 1 to 4. The first could be set to a value before the second range was multiplied by 3.

If there are performance reasons not to then are they overcome by otherwise having to to copy values in and out of completely new variables and perform more complicated processes to achieve certain algorithms that could otherwise be done on a very low level?

Comment: Registers are created by the manufacturer of the CPU. You should not call memory locations "registers".

Comment: Feel free to try an edit improving the terminology. Or should I change "register" to "memory range" or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this trick when it is done in assembly: optimizers have been routinely making use of knowing where parts of an integer are to save CPU cycles and reduce the size of the code. For example, when a 32-bit integer variable is initialized to a value that fits in only 16 bits, optimizing compilers would replace the instruction that stores a 32-bit value in memory with a faster instruction that stores a 16-bit value to the lower bits of the variable, and clear the upper 16 bits. Moreover, many optimizers would go even further: if a constant is divisible by 2^16, they would store the value divided by 2^16 to the upper 16 bits, and clear lower 16 bits.

Some architectures restrict such manipulations to addresses of certain properties, for example, by requiring all 4-byte memory load/store instructions to be done at addresses divisible by four. These restrictions may reduce applicability of partial-value writing tricks.